# contentOffset not working when return to page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have one `UIScrollView` & one `UIButton` in my page.when I click one my button I go to next page with this code:

```
SearchViewController *add =  [[SearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in next page I have one `TableView`. Now I want change contentOffset my ScrollView when click on any cell.when call one method in my ScrollViewController this method working but my `ScrollView` in my method is nil and `contentOffset` not working!!! why?

please guide me about that.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[scrolObject ChangeToLastObject:1];    
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

this method is in ScrollViewController

```
- (void)ChangeToLastObject:(NSString*)idstation{
    myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(myScrollView.frame.size.width * (2), 0);

}
```

why myScrollView in top method is nil???

myScrollView is `IBOutlet` (nonatomic,strong)

Comment: I assume that 'scrolObject' is an object that would contain reference of first view controller. But where do you assign reference to that property??

Comment: @SalmanZaidi what my friend???

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with this line:

```
[scrolObject ChangeToLastObject:1];
```

The primary issue is that `scrolObject` appears to be intended as a pointer to an instance of your `ScrollViewController`.  It is probably uninitialized.  Even if it were correctly initialized, it's poor design to give view controllers pointers to each other.

So how to communicate between view controllers?  There's a half dozen answers to that question, including this one:  Don't do it at all.  Instead have your view controllers write to and read from the same model.

Your view controller with the table can write to the model when a table selection is made, and your `ScrollViewController` can read the model and set it's scroll view's content offset accordingly on `viewWillAppear:`.

Other things wrong with the line:  `scrolObject` should probably be spelled `scrollObject`, `ChangeToLastObject:` should definitely be spelled starting with lowercase `C`, you're passing a literal int = 1, but the method is declared to take an `NSString *`.

Comment: thanks alot my friend . I write correct call method because my ChangeToLastObject: method it's working but when I can change  contentOffset myScrollView this method not working. I use breakpoint for this problem and I know this myScrollView is nil!!!